# Sent many requests asynchonized to http server but it only serves a few request at a time

Tags: java, jersey, grizzly

I'm facing to this issue:
I have a grizzly embedded http server running. By sending 200 asynchronous requests to the server (using ExecutorService in java), I thought it would serve all these request at a time but I release that the server only serves 8 request in a time and no error thrown. Please give me an explaination for this. Do I misunderstanding anything?

Comment: Try to use connection pool in the server and configure/increment the number of connections,  this should improve the performance. Following link can give you an starting context: https://docs.jelastic.com/jdbc-connection-pool

Comment: It seems connection pool used for controlling connections to db, but http sv. Actually I tried this config "jersey.config.client.async.threadPoolSize" but there is no efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that all requests have arrived at the server? Do you release resources after the program is processed? If you send multiple requests at the same time and exceed the program's tolerance limit, you will wait. Have you done all these controls?

Comment: Sorry I dont really understand. My http server serves rest API, all configuration are set as default. I thought that for any incoming request, the server would create a new thread to execute and release all resources allocated whenever it done. Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: I'm sure that all requests have arrived at the server. At client side I see that all request was sent, but at server side, I see that server serve only a few request at a time until all request are served

Comment: You can refer to the official documentation（https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html）. ExecutorService will reject new tasks if it is not controlled,

Comment: Ah, I've just found out an bottleneck problem, thank you so much